# Handlebars usage in Bootstrap based template - how to iterate over many ul and lis

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, handlebars.js

I'm using Bootstrap to build my website, which is showing results based on jSON API call to youtube's API. Imagine a grid of youtube video clips with their thumbnails only, when you click one of them, it opens modal with player for this video.

That's nice, and I am trying to implement it with the help of handlebars.

I'm stuck because I can't just iterate with {{each}} on the results that I get from youtube, because for displaying them I (and this is because of Bootstrap) I need to add separate

```
 <ul> </ul> 
for every 4 
 <li></li>s.
```

I need to produce this

```
<ul>
 <li> ... </li>
 <li> ... </li>
 <li> ... </li>
 <li> ... </li>
</ul>
```

then again new

```
 <ul> with 4     <li>s inside 

 <ul>
  <li> ... </li>
  <li> ... </li>
  <li> ... </li>
  <li> ... </li>
</ul>
```

For Now in one single

```
  <ul> </ul>
```

I am able to do 4

```
  <li> </li>
```

with the usage of handlebars,

but this is if I get only four results from youtube, but if I get let's say 16 results, how I can tell Handlebars to put

```
 <ul> </ul> 
for every 4 
  <li>s
```

That's my question.

Here is my current template inside one UL

```
<ul class="thumbnails" id="mostpopular">
          <script id="mostpopular-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
          {{#each this}}
          <li class="span3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="{{url}}">
              <img src="{{thumb}}" alt="{{title}}">
            </a>
              <div class="yt-caption">
                <strong>{{title}}</strong><br>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          {{/each}}
          </script>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't do this:

```
<ul>
    <script ...>
    </script>
</ul>
```

That's a bad habit that often leads to "where did my template go?" questions when you `$('ul').html('')` to reset things. You're better off keeping your template `<script>`s away from your content.

Now back to the matter at hand. If your `<li>`s are going to be about the same size then you can get away with simple CSS to tile them. Just set a width on your `<li>`s and float them inside your `<ul>`:

```
ul {
    overflow: hidden; /* To make the <ul> size itself to contain all the <li>s */
}
li {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;  /* Or whatever works, you might want a height as well. */
}​
```

Then just throw all the `<li>`s into the `<ul>` and let the browser take care of it; for example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/azWgp/

If you must do it in the template, then chunk your data into an array-of-arrays inside JavaScript and use nested `{{#each}}`s in the template. Something like this:

```
{{#each chunks}}
    <ul>
        {{#each this}}
            <li>...</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
{{/each}}
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ABEzn/

You could also add your own helper but that would just be the above approach shuffled around a bit.